# Amazon EventBridge rule S3 put object event cannot trigger the AWS StepFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

After setting the EventBridge, S3 put object event still cannot trigger the StepFuction.

However, I tried to change the event rule to EC2 status. It's working !!!

I also try to change the rule to S3 all event, but it still not working.

**Amazon EventBridge:**

Event pattern:

```
     { 
      "source": ["aws.s3"],
      "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
      "detail": {
                 "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
                 "eventName": ["PutObject"],
                 "requestParameters": {
                 "bucketName": ["MY_BUCKETNAME"]
                 }
     }
```

Target(s):

```
  Type:Step Functions state machine
    ARN:arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:stateMachine:MY_FUNCTION_NAME
```

Reference:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html

Comment: Did you enable CloudTrial for S3 events? Did you verify that the S3 events are detected by the CT?

Comment: @Marcin  Yes, I follow the reference and create the  CloudTrial for S3 events. However, it still cannot trigger the stepfunction

Answer (score 4):

Your step function isn't being triggered because the PutObject events aren't being published to cloudtrail. S3 operations are classified as data events so you must enable Data events when creating your cloudTrail. The tutorial says next next and create which seems to suggest no additional options need to be selected. By default, Data Events on the next step (step 2  - Choose log events - as of this writing) is not checked. You have to check it and fill up the bottom part to specify if all buckets/events are to be logged.